# Missing 1 required positional argument - Python

Tags: python, recursion, types, memoization

```
TypeError: sequence() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n', sequence()
```

Apparently when using `sequence(n-1) + sequence(n-2)` the n is not using the value from the function, what can I do to fix it?

```
memo = {0:0,1:1}
def sequence(type, n):
if type == "fibonacci":
    if not n in memo:
        memo[n] = sequence(n-1) + sequence(n-2)
    else:
        return memo[n]
```

Comment: you need to pass the type argument into your recursive calls, i.e `memo[n] = sequence(type, n-1) + sequence(type, n-2)`

Comment: As a side note, don't use `type` as a variable name, since there is already a built-in by that name

Comment: `if n not in memo:` should also make things better

Comment: and you still need to return the value of memo[n]. So I think you'd be better off by removing the else and return it in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sequence(type, n-1) + sequence(type, n-2)
```

The error is explicit, the function `sequence` is expecting two parameters, but you're passing only one. As a side note, you should remove the `else`, and make sure that `return memo[n]` is executed at the end - because your function must *always* return a value, otherwise the recursion won't work.